# Hover state on mobile/tablet devices

Tags: jquery, css, mobile, responsive-design, tablet

I have information that appears over a div when you hover over it on a desktop but also acts as a hyperlink. Mobile and tablet obviously you can't hover over these elements, so it just goes to the destination without showing the information prior. Is there anyway to get these elements to show the information when touched on and then proceed to the hyperlink destination when touched again in CSS?

Here is the page: http://thefooddepot.org/donations

Thank you for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, on iOS devices, typically the :hover state is triggered upon clicking the item. On Android devices, the :hover state is ignored and the click action is taken immediately (as you describe).

In order to get the behavior you want you may need to use device sniffing and if you notice you are on a touch device you explicitly add an additional click handler which will reveal the overlay.

The overlay, of course, will have its own click handler which will then take the user to the ultimate destination.

In order to determine whether or not you are on a touch device you can use the modernizr library and look for the `.touch` class that is added by the library, or use any other number of methods to [detect the device type](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=detect%20device%20type).